# Share UDFs in Multi hiveserver

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions

In our production environment,we have multi hiveserver2 for high availibility.User create permenent UDFs by running

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2//hs1.name.com"    
add jar <hdfs://ns:8020/path/udf.jar>
create  function myfunc as 'com.test.udf.UDF_CLASS' using jar 'hdfs://ns:8020/path/udf.jar'
```

User connect to hs1.name.com is OK,but user get *function not found* ERROR when using beeline connect another hiveserver2 to call the UDF,like

```
beeline -u "jdbc:hive2//hs2.name.com"
select myfunc(id) from table1
```

Error messages is

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:7 Invalid function 'myfunc' (state=42000,code=10011)`

After restart hiveserver2 on hs2.name.com,user can call the UDF correctly.
  Is there someway not to restart hiveserver2 but told hiveserver2 to reload UDFs information from metastore?

Thanks  @Kishore, `reload function` is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
USE RELOAD FUNCTION;
```

As of HIVE-2573, creating permanent functions in one Hive CLI session may not be reflected in HiveServer2 or other Hive CLI sessions, if they were started before the function was created. Issuing RELOAD FUNCTION within a HiveServer2 or HiveCLI session will allow it to pick up any changes to the permanent functions that may have been done by a different HiveCLI session.

ref - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/ReloadFunction